# PHP: How to create an array automatically with same keys

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I have an object which contains some information about persons:

```
name, age, type
```

For an xml-request I need my person array like this:

```
<persons itc=3>
  <person id=1 type=H age=30 />
  <person id=2 type=H age=35 />
  <person id=3 type=H age=6 />
</persons>
```

I would like to create this automatically for example with foreach, all attributes in the xml knots are marked with an "@" before, so that the function, which is called after this knows, how to build the xml:

```
foreach($object->getPersons as $person) {
  $array['persons'] = array(
     'person' = array(
        '@id' =>  $person->getId(),
        '@type' =>  $person->getType(),
        '@age' =>  $person->getAge(),
     )
  )
}
```

But, as I know, it is not possible to have an array with more than one key with the same name, logical...! Bute How can I create this xml-schema ou of my object? Can someone give me a hint?
THANKS!

Comment: A multi-dimensional array perhaps?

Comment: wait so whats the final output? an xml that contains data from an array?

Comment: @Zwen2012 whats the context here, are you planning to create an xml in the end?

Comment: Yes, I am planning an XML!

Comment: @Zwen2012 if you want to create an xml, why are you creating an array? use `SimpleXMLElement`

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to name all the arrays to the same name, why even name them?
Instead of creating an associative array, just create a normal indexed array, Something like:

```
$array['persons'] = array();
foreach($object->getPersons as $person) {
  $array['persons'][] = array( "@id"   => $person->getId(),
                               "@type" => $person->getType(),
                               "@age"  => $person->getAge() );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A multi-dimensional array of `$array` variable should work like shown below:

```
foreach($object->getPersons as $person) {
  $array['persons'][] = array(       // [] for auto increment.
     'person' = array(
        '@id' =>  $person->getId(),
        '@type' =>  $person->getType(),
        '@age' =>  $person->getAge(),
     )
  )
}
```

You would then get each persons information using

```
$array['persons'][1] //for example.
```

Comment: that should be `$array['persons'][]`, if you want your array to make sense

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the way I look at makes sense either way. But I see where you are coming from. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a multidimensional array

```
foreach($object->getPersons as $person) { 
   $array['persons'] = array(
      Array(
        'person' = array( '@id' => $person->getId(), '@type' => $person->getType(), '@age' => $person->getAge(), 
      ), 
      Array(
        'person' = array( '@id' => $person->getId(), '@type' => $person->getType(), '@age' => $person->getAge(), 
      ),
    ) 
  ) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, you're going to create an xml, use that values and create the XML directly instead. Use `SimpleXMLElement` to do so. You didn't give a sample object dummy data so I'l just create an example:

```
$persons = array(
    (object) array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Person 1', 'age' => 200, 'type' => 'H'),
    (object) array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Person 2', 'age' => 300, 'type' => 'B'),
);

$count = count($persons);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<persons/>', LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
$xml->addAttribute('itc', $count);
foreach($persons as $person) {
    $person_node = $xml->addChild('person', null);
    foreach($person as $attribute => $value) {
        $person_node->addAttribute($attribute, $value);
    }
}

echo htmlentities($xml->asXML());
```

Should output (based on dummy data):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<persons itc="2">
    <person id="1" name="Person 1" age="200" type="H"/>
    <person id="2" name="Person 2" age="300" type="B"/>
</persons>
```

Comment: The Problem is, this will not be the only object which belongs to the finished XML. Thats only one part!

Comment: @Zwen2012 if thats the case its still okay, you're still going to create an xml in the end, that is just my example. Of course, you will need to build the array first, and since you did'nt gave an example i just made a dummy data

Comment: You are right, I try another way, btw, your example works fine! THANKS!

Comment: @Zwen2012 sure glad i could help no prob